# Xpath seems to exist but the element cannot be found through code

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to fetch an element using HTML Agility Pack (C#) but it keeps returning null.

The HTML looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEubD.jpg) (sorry for the image).

I can successfully find the first node I marked with the arrow using the following xpath:
`var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='listing-container']");`

But it says this node only has one "text" child while in the HTML it clearly has other div I need to access (as in the image).

How can I access this node with `class = c-listing`?
Does not seem to be in a frame or anything like that.

Thank for you help, I am not experienced in this field.
Cheers

Comment: This seems like a react website - meaning html body is generated by javascript. If your scraper is not running/emulating javascript it'll see different html (or nothing at all). Could you provide with the url you're scraping what are you using for the http requests?

Comment: https://www.ricardocuisine.com/recettes/plats-principaux/boeuf/sort/recent/page/1 is just an example. I am using HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question accordingly. In this case you should have HTML as inline string constant in the code. Please note that there is 99% chance the HTML you claim to contain that div does not actually contain it (as @Granitosaurus said you are likely trying to scrape dynamic site) but at very least you should be able to diagnose the issue better.

Comment: Don't say "sorry for the image".   ***Just don't use images for code or markup.***

Comment: This website is indeed using dynamically generated content. I wrote extensive blog on this subject (very similar website in the example): https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html take a crack at this and if you can't figure it please form a new question with more, concise details and how far you've gotten - then we can help you out! :)